# Rank of Upper Triangular Block Matrix under Special conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have been looking around for an answer to this question for a bit. I'm asking about this because it would really help me with a problem I have. Essentially, what I want to know is whether a block matrix of the form

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 
I & B \\
0 & C
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix, $B$ is some arbitrary matrix, $C$ is a non-singular matrix. Is it true that rank$A$ = rank$I$ + rank$C$? I know this is true when $B = 0$ but not sure about something like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for block upper triangular matrices, we have the same result than for regular matrices:

$$
\det(A) = \det(I)\cdot \det(C) = \det(C) \neq 0
$$

so $A$ is invertible and should have full rank. This coincides with the sum of the ranks of $A$ and $C$ because they also have full rank, since that they are invertible.

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful, thank you so much. Was not thinking of approaching this using determinants. I must admit my linear algebra is a tad rusty. Thanks again!